# dynamically created dropdowns with populated arrays don't update using angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, cascadingdropdown, dropdownbox

My first dropdown loads correctly on page load, but the child dropdown loads after the first dropdown from localstorage.  Problem is when I load the 2nd dropdown and assign it the default value I can no longer change its value.  http://jsfiddle.net/silvajeff/x2nrX/3/

```
angular.module('demoApp', []).controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
  //my first drop down loads with the page
  $scope.options = [
     { label: 'one', value: 1 },
     { label: 'two', value: 2 },
     { label: 'three', value: 3 },
     { label: 'four', value: 4 },
     { label: 'five', value: 5 }
  ];  

  $scope.firstSelect = $scope.options[3];  

//the second drop down loads after the first makes a selection. In the real code I am     populating the second from localstorage, but once it's assigned its default value I cannot change it.    
var init = function(){
   //depends on what was selected in first select
    $scope.captions = [
       { name: 'A', value: 'a' },
       { name: 'B', value: 'b' },
       { name: 'C', value: 'c' },
       { name: 'D', value: 'd' },
       { name: 'E', value: 'e' }
   ]; 
    $scope.secondSelect = $scope.captions[1];
}   
init();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change ng-if for ng-show and second drop down will work http://jsfiddle.net/Wc4CQ/

```
<body ng-app="demoApp">
    <div ng-controller="DemoController">

        <div>

            <select ng-model="firstSelect"
                ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options">
            </select>
<br><br>
            <select  ng-show="firstSelect.value == '4'" ng-model="secondSelect"
                ng-options="opt as opt.name for opt in captions">
            </select><br>
            The first select value is {{ firstSelect.value }}<br>
            Why can't I get the second select value to update: {{ secondSelect.value }}
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

or if you have  to us ng-if please see here : http://jsfiddle.net/y5Bvv/

```
<body ng-app="demoApp">
    <div ng-controller="DemoController">
        <div>
            <select ng-model="firstSelect" ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options"></select>
            <br>
            <br>
            <select ng-if="firstSelect.value == '4'" ng-model="secondSelect.select" ng-options="opt as opt.name for opt in captions"></select>
            <br>The first select value is {{ firstSelect.value }}
            <br>Why can't I get the second select value to update: {{ secondSelect.select.value }}</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('demoApp', []).controller('DemoController', function ($scope) {
    //my first drop down loads with the page
    $scope.options = [{
        label: 'one',
        value: 1
    }, {
        label: 'two',
        value: 2
    }, {
        label: 'three',
        value: 3
    }, {
        label: 'four',
        value: 4
    }, {
        label: 'five',
        value: 5
    }];
    $scope.firstSelect = $scope.options[3];

    //the second drop down loads after the first makes a selection. In the real code I am populating the second from localstorage, but once it's assigned its default value I cannot change it.    
    var init = function () {
        //depends on what was selected in first select
        $scope.captions = [{
            name: 'A',
            value: 'a'
        }, {
            name: 'B',
            value: 'b'
        }, {
            name: 'C',
            value: 'c'
        }, {
            name: 'D',
            value: 'd'
        }, {
            name: 'E',
            value: 'e'
        }];
        $scope.secondSelect = {};
        $scope.secondSelect.select = $scope.captions[1];
    }
    init();

});
```